# Finding weight in Megagrams (Mg) given circumference and density

Tags: geometry, physics, 3d, volume, spheres

Glaciers often deposit large rocks called erratics. The granite rock has a circumference of 9.5 m. Assuming it conforms to the shape of a sphere, what would be its weight in Megagrams (Mg), where 1 Mg = 1,000 Kg ≈ 1 US ton. The average density of granite is $2.70\ \mathrm{g} \cdot \mathrm{cm}^{-3}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you please update your question with what you think should be the approach to solve this problem, and where you are getting stuck. We will be glad to guide you further.

Comment: I'm getting stuck converting the units. I got the volume (14.48) and the density (2.70 g cm ^-3) but I am confused what the units of volume are and how to convert it to megagrams.

Comment: see update to my hint, can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. Given a circumference of the sphere, find its volume $V$.
2. With volume and density, find the mass.
3. Convert the mass to the desired units.

**UPDATE**

Since the circumference is $$C=2\pi r \iff r = \frac{C}{2\pi}$$ and $V = 4\pi r^3/2$, you have
$$
\begin{split}
V &= \frac43\pi r^3
   = \frac43 \pi \left(\frac{C}{2\pi}\right)^3 
   = \frac{4}{3 \cdot 8} \frac{\pi}{\pi^3} C^3 
   = \frac{C^3}{6\pi^2} \\
  &= \frac{(9.5 \mathrm{m})^3}{6 \pi^2}
   = \frac{9.5^3}{6 \pi^2} \textrm{m}^3 \\
  &\approx 14.478 \mathrm{m}^3.
\end{split}
$$

Your density $\rho$ is in the wrong units, so to find the mass $M$ you have to do the following:
$$
\begin{split}
M &= \rho V
   = 2.7 \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{cm}^3} \times 14.478 \mathrm{m}^3 \\
  &= 2.7 \frac{\mathrm{g}}
             {\mathrm{\left(cm \times \frac{1 \mathrm{m}}
                                           {100 \mathrm{cm}}\right)}^3}
    \times 14.478 \mathrm{m}^3 \\
  &= \frac{2.7 \mathrm{g}}{\left(\frac{1}{100} \mathrm{m}\right)^3}
    \times 14.478 \mathrm{m}^3 \\ \\
  &= 2.7 \times 100^3 \times 14.478 \frac{\mathrm{g} \cdot \mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{m}^3} \\
  &= 39090.6 \mathrm{g}.
\end{split}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thanks so much!